# Inserting The UID into Firebase Database Only once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the main activity of Android Studio, immediately after anonymously signing in into firebase, I have this line of code:

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Online Users").push().setValue(currentUser.getUid().toString());
```

So, the UID of current user will be saved into firebase under the child "Online Users". Good. Problem is, when I open the app for the second or third time, or if I navigate from another activity to the main activity, this line of code gets executed again, and now I have several identical entries in the firebase. I mean, one UID has been pushed into firebase several times. But I don't want that. I want only one copy of each UID there. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want a specific value to be unique in the Firebase Database, model it as the key of a list.

In your case that means that instead of calling `push()` you actually use the UID as the key:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Online Users").child(currentUser.getUid().toString()).setValue(true);
```

Now whenever the user comes online again, they're just writing `true` to the same location again.

---

Note that the same user can come online from multiple devices. If you are trying to build a presence system, tracking what users are online, I recommend studying the [sample presence system in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) which handles the edge cases correctly.